# $(window).resize(): Before

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

Is it possible of getting the width/height of browser each time **BEFORE** the resize() is triggered?

```
$(window).resize(function() {

});
```

This is due to I'm calculating the difference before/after browser has resize().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would have to store the previous value, a little like this

```
var prevHeight = 0;
var prevWidth = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    prevHeight = $(window).height();
    prevWidth = $(window).width();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    var currentHeight = $(window).height();
    var currentWidth = $(window).width();

    //do difference stuff

    prevHeight = currentHeight;
    prevWidth = currentWidth;
});
```

Comment: I thought there was special jquery to catch that :) But this is cool for me too:)

Comment: @Roylee if this solution worked for you than you should probably appreciate the persons efforts and mark it answer.

Comment: @iMatoria Of course, I'm just wait to see if there's better answer comparing to his.

Comment: Doesn't this only help with the height of the window on load, not each time BEFORE there is a resize event?

Comment: @bafromca because prevHeight and prevWidth get set again at the end of $(window).resize(), this will work for every resize event.

Comment: Take into account that $(window).resize() fires several times if user resize window manually.